# react-router-dom PrivateRoute with redux endless loading

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

After reloading the PrivateRoute redirects to ***/login*** before the start of authorization, because initial *redux* state is ***false*** for both of them.

Those are logs from router:

> PrivateRoute.js:16  *Loading*: **false**  *isAuthenticated*: **false**
>   PrivateRoute.js:16  *Loading*: **true**   *isAuthenticated*: **false**
>   PrivateRoute.js:16  *Loading*: **false**  *isAuthenticated*: **true**

It **is working correctly**, I just need a way to distinguish initial state from not authenticated user.

### My attempt

1. My first thought was changing initial state for *isLoading* to **true**:
   *Weird behavior. Page doesn't load at all. Even whole App component can't mount so I don't really know what is going on.*
2. Changing initial state for isAuthenticated to null and changing conditions from

```
isLoading ?
```

to

```
isAuthenticated === null ?
```

> *(Router below)*

Everything seems fine until PrivateRoute is required. When debugger is at the *if* statement everything freezes again.

---

This is my PrivateRoute component as I found [Here](https://medium.com/@tomlarge/private-routes-with-react-router-dom-28e9f40c7146)

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Spinner from "../../components/Spinner";

const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  isLoading,
  isAuthenticated,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoading: state.auth.isLoading,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: It won't work, because using a render prop like this will not trigger an update when the new state comes in via props, because react cannot detect the change in Route's render prop since it still points to the same function. So according to react's diffing nothing has changed.

Comment: "It is working correctly, I just need a way to distinguish initial state from not authenticated user." Are you setting `isAuthenticated` in redux? Why are you trying to distinguish between initial state & not authenticated user?

Comment: Sounds like attempt #1 is what you should be shooting for. There's nothing wrong with the code, just your implementation. Figure out why #1 didn't work, that sounds like what you really want to do.The real problem is that if `isAuthenticated` and `isLoading` can be false at the same time - you have no choice but to redirect, so there's nothing logically wrong with that. (Also, might I suggest `isAuthenticating` rather than `isLoading` to make it crystal clear what is happening).

Comment: @deowk I added the whole code in the edit. The component is connected to the store and state updates are triggered

Comment: @displacedtexan Yes, im setting isAuthenticated via redux.  The need for distinguishing is, so that the initial state is identical to user not authorizated and the PrivateRoute is redirecting to */login* before the user even starts loading

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to figure this out but it's really strange. I have tried to debugg or log anything to get a hint where the problem is but everything just freezes as soon as I change it to *true* and refresh. I will post an answer if I get this method to work.

Comment: @jjablonski If it's too messy to repurpose `isLoading` create yourself something else in redux like `isAuthenticating` and use it in place of `isLoading`. At least that way you won't have to figure out why `isLoading` breaks everything. (repurposing stuff is always a bad idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I spent around 5 hours to realise I forgot import something in the **Spinner** ... 
Thank you all for effort